# Why does the compiler copy RDI to another register, and then copy it back to RDI inside a loop?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm analysing a piece of inefficient code, but some of it is so confusing?

Original code:

```c
#include <string.h>

void lowwer(char *str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {
    str[i] -= ('A' - 'a');
  }
}
```

Assembly code (generated by clang 13 with -Og option):

```
lowwer:
  pushq %r14 # use saved-registers
  pushq %rbx
  pushq %rax
  # guard do while
  cmpb  $0, (%rdi) # compare &str with null (check if strlen(str) == 0)
  je    .LBB0_3
  # loop initialization
  movq  %rdi, %r14 # %r14 = str
  xorl  %ebx, %ebx # clear %rbx (for more compact encoding)
.LBB0_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  addb  $32, (%r14,%rbx) # subtract -32 from str[i] ('A' - 'a' = -32)
  addq  $1, %rbx # ++i
  movq  %r14, %rdi # seems meaningless here?
  callq strlen@PLT
  cmpq  %rbx, %rax # check i < strlen(str)
  ja    .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3: # end
  addq  $8, %rsp # ???
  popq  %rbx # free registers
  popq  %r14
  retq
```

1. what does the instruction `movq %r14, %rdi` is doing? It seemed meangingless because `%r14` holding the string pointer and the `rdi` is the same.
2. What the intention of the instruction `addq $8, %rsp`. Looks clueless.

Comment: What is the point of this exercise? To make this code "efficient" there are two steps: 1) Move `strlen` call out of the loop 2) Compile with `-O3`.

Comment: To expand on Eugene's point [Example in godbolt of doing exactly that](https://godbolt.org/z/oq1Gas1o8) it dramatically changes the output and reduces the amount of registers used. The better question to me is "What is clang doing!?"

Comment: Also because this assumes c style strings [we don't even need `strlen`](https://godbolt.org/z/GWPrP855c)

Comment: While you're at it, if we are assuming ASCII anyway, you could use `str[i] |= 0x20;`, though honestly I don't see it being an improvement over the existing code.

Comment: On the first entry to the loop, `rdi` and `r14` do both contain the string pointer (because of the preceding `movq %rdi, %r14`), so the `movq %r14, %rdi` is redundant - that time.  But on subsequent iterations, we jump back to `.LBB0_2`.  At this point, `%rdi` has been trashed by the call to `strlen`, but `%r14` has been preserved, as fuz noted.  So we move it back into `%rdi` because that's where `strlen` expects to find its argument.  There might have been a way to avoid the redundant move on the first iteration, but I suspect it would complicate the code overall.

Comment: @Mgetz: "What is clang doing!?" - the same thing GCC is doing, if you enable full optimization for both (`-O3`).  https://godbolt.org/z/h3hP5E4n4 Or use current trunk GCC where `-ftree-vectorize` is on at `-O2`, matching clang.  Adding `32` to each byte is obviously done much more efficiently with SIMD 16B at a time.  But it couldn't do that for the original, because it can't prove that these changes to `str[]` contents won't introduce a new `0` byte for strlen to find: `-32` plus 32 produces 0 without UB. Of course, there are missed optimizations, like loading a separate 8-byte `set1(32)`...

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA: That would _actually_ work to lowercase A-Z (and leave a-z intact), where as the original code is adding 0x20 to all values mod 256, being some kind of 'caesar cipher' for the already lower case letters (and symbols from 0x20 to 0x3f, including digits 0-9).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rdi` is a caller-saved register and is hence trashed by the call to `strlen`.  To preserve its contents, the compiler emitted code to  move its contents to `r14`, copying it back once every iteration as an argument to `strlen`.

The `addq $8, %rsp` instruction releases stack space previously allocated by `pushq %rax`.  This stack space was allocated to satisfy the stack alignment requirements imposed by the amd64 SysV ABI.

Refer to the amd64 SysV ABI supplement for the full calling convention and a list of caller/callee saved registers.